# List not updating when using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

First question here so bare with me.

I'm currently working on developing an automated web scraping system for my company's database, however i've ran in to a bit of an issue i can't seem to figure out.

I won't post the entire code here as it's a lot to sift through, but explaining the issue will hopefully be enough with a little snippet.

Partway down my Python code, i extract the data from my Excel spreadsheet in to a list, however for some reason, the list doesn't actually update until after the program has terminated?

For example the length of the list will print 0 after writing to it, but the next time i run the program, the list is full and printing the correct number of elements.

This is troublesome as i need to work with that list directly after by comparing it to another list, to check for missing data...any ideas what this could be? The code is below:

```
    excel_updates_check_inner_list = []
    excel_updates_check_list = []

    for i in range(0, excel_list_size-1):
        updates_stock_name = db.cell(row= 2+i, column= 2).value
        updates_stock_location = db.cell(row= 2+i, column= 3).value
        updates_stock_dimensions = db.cell(row= 2+i, column= 4).value
        updates_stock_price = db.cell(row= 2+i, column= 5).value
        updates_stock_hire = db.cell(row= 2+i, column= 6).value
        excel_updates_check_inner_list = [updates_stock_name, updates_stock_location, updates_stock_dimensions, updates_stock_price, updates_stock_hire]
        excel_updates_check_list.append(excel_updates_check_inner_list)


    excel_updates_check_list.sort()
    print(len(excel_updates_check_list))
```

I've tried saving the excel sheet directly before executing this chunk of code, but still with no luck.

Comment: One thing I had with opening Excel spreadsheets is that depending on the mode, it may be asking for exclusive access. Be sure nobody else has it opened. Incidentally, it might be easier to read a spreadsheet into a DataFrame provided by pandas.

Comment: What happens if you try to print all the variables inside the for loop before appending to the main list?

Comment: @UdonN00dle have just tried it. it prints in order as you would expect, each name, location, dimension, price and hire, then it moves on to the next stock. Interesting...so maybe it's to do with the appending?

Comment: Yes, it's probably to do with append inside a for loop, I recently had a similar issue. Could you try remove the 'inner_list' variable and append directly? Something like `check_list.append([[updates_stock_name, ...]])`. If this doesn't work, another idea is to append a copy of the inner list as `check_list.append(excel_updates_check_inner_list.copy())`

Comment: @UdonN00dle Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately neither solution has worked, really quite a bizarre scenario, not sure what could be causing it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by just using Pandas instead. For some reason there is some kind of read-in lag with Openpyxl. With Pandas i just created the dataframe and extracted the information from there in to subsequent lists.